# Finding $f\in C( \mathbb R)$ such that for some integer $n>1$, $f^n(x)=x,\,\forall x \in \mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such that for some integer $n>1$, $f^n(x)=x,\,\forall x \in \mathbb R$; then is it true that either $f(x)=x,\,\forall x \in \mathbb R$ or $f(x)=-x,\,\forall x \in \mathbb R$?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Worth looking at solutions for $n=2$ to start, if nothing else.

Comment: @πr8: Honestly , finding any other function than what I have mentioned seems real hard(if any) . Do you have one ?

Comment: Consider a simple function like $f(x)=ax+b$ and see if you can choose $a,b$ so that $f(f(x))=x$.

Comment: I think if you want an monotonous increasing functions then $f(x)=x$ is the only one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$f(x) = -x+b, f^2(x)= -(-x+b)+b=x$ is a counter example.